# Failed to create LLM 'stablelm' GGUF ctransformers Google Colab

Tags: ctransformers

I often get error from `ctransformers` when importing some GGUF models with `model_type = stablelm` in Google Colab. Here is the code example

```py
from ctransformers import AutoModelForCausalLM

llm = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("TheBloke/Marx-3B-v3-GGUF", model_file="marx-3b-v3.Q3_K_S.gguf", model_type='stablelm')
print(llm("AI is going to"))
```

It actually downloaded the `.gguf` file from repo, but returned this error message

```py
RuntimeError: Failed to create LLM 'stablelm' from '/root/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--TheBloke--Marx-3B-v3-GGUF/blobs/fb16032da1b4f68d465cb7b2164c5305be8a008657ed0cd6cbb91b3a94b032ee'.
```

Comment: seems like you are using a different model type, try using mistral or llama. Also please share repo link

Comment: @JawwadAhmed In this example i use `TheBloke/Marx-3B-v3-GGUF` from huggingface repo. The model type is stablelm. I've tried llama and mistral for it, but it returned the same error : `Failed to create LLM '{model_type}'`

Comment: reference: https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/CausalLM-7B-GGUF/discussions/3

Everyone is waiting for ctransformers to get an update.

Comment: @JawwadAhmed that link referred to a different error from ctransformers where the colab notebook crashes instead of returning `Failed to create LLM` error

Answer (score 0):

```
from ctransformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoConfig, Config
```

Hi I tried with below option with mistral but i am getting below error

```
RuntimeError: Failed to create LLM 'mistral' from 'C:\LLM\Mistral\mistral-7b-instruct-v0.2.Q4_K_M.gguf'. Error.
```

Any help?

```
    conf = AutoConfig(Config(temperature=0.25,
                             max_new_tokens=512))

    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("C:\LLM\Mistral\mistral-7b-instruct-v0.2.Q4_K_M.gguf",
                                                     model_file="TheBloke/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2-GGUF",
                                                     config = conf,
                                                     device_map="cpu",
                                                     model_type="mistral")


    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(TheBloke/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2-GGUF,                                                     model_file="C:\LLM\Mistral\mistral-7b-instruct-v0.2.Q4_K_M.gguf",
                                                     config = conf,
                                                     device_map="cpu",
                                                     model_type="mistral")

    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("C:\LLM\Mistral\mistral-7b-instruct-v0.2.Q4_K_M.gguf",
                                                                                                         config = conf,
                                                     device_map="cpu",
                                                     model_type="mistral")


   model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_path_or_repo_id="C:\LLM\Mistral\mistral-7b-instruct-v0.2.Q4_K_M.gguf",
                                                 
                                                 model_type="mistral",
                                                 config = conf,
                                                 device_map="cpu",
                                                 local_files_only = True
                                                 )
```